# yiic.bat file not running due to php not recognized

Tags: php, windows, yii, cmd

I am trying to set up yii for the first time and use yiic.bat.  I have been reading the post with the same issues and they all say add the directory to the windows path.  However something isn't working out. Here is what I did:

My computer:
Windows 7
Wamp
php directory : 
C:\wamp\bin\php\
yii-1.1.14.f0fee9.tar.gz

1: I downloaded, unzipped and put it in my C:\wamp\www directory
2: I renamed the folder as yii
3: I added ;C:\wamp\bin\php\ to the path for windows
4: I restarted my computer to make sure the path took affect
5: I created a file called myrun.bat in C:\wamp\www directory
   the content of the file: 
     set PATH=%PATH%;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3
     cmd
6: When i try to run the cmd pops up
7: I type php yii/framework/yiic.php webapp myfirstsite

The cmd results are:
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Any type of advice would help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the php.exe is, you should find the php.exe's directory ,maybe C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\bin, and add this path to the %PATH%

Comment: Thank you!  you were close enough to put me in the right direction.  I tried C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\bin, restarted and got the same error so i tried  C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

No need for any %PATH% variable, just fallow these steps:

1. When you download the Yii from the website, there is a folder called
   `framework` inside the rar file you downloaded. Copy that folder to
   your webserver root directory, which is in my case `C:\wamp\www`.
2. In the `www` folder also create a new folder called `NewYiiApp`.
   Inside this folder your new Yii application will be created and here you will write your controllers, models and
   classes.
3. After that open your cmd using Start->Run->cmd.
4. Using CMD navigate to the `framework` folder using cd
   `C:/wamp/www/framework`.
5. Open Windows Explorer and naigate to the PHP directory. In my case
   it is located in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13`
6. Ensure that this folder contains php.exe file
7. Paste the following line in the already opened CMD
8. `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe yiic webapp
   C:/wamp/www/NewYiiApp`, but change my PHP folder path with yours
9. It will ask you: Create a web application under
   `C:/wamp/www/NewYiiApp`? Type Yes and hit ENTER.

Hope I helped!